# Why is Windows 10 is allowing removable media access even when it has been denied in GPO?

Tags: windows-10

I have a stand-alone windows 10 system. I wish to deny access to removable media. I enable the 'deny-all' setting in 'Local Group Policy/AdministrativeTemplates/System/RemovableStorageAccess'. I do gpupdate /force and restart. When I log back in gpresults say that the setting has been applied, but when I plug in a CD drive or USB drive I can still access it. Can you tell me what the problem is?

Comment: To check whether the settings are being applied, is there a Registry value called `Deny_All` in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices`?

Comment: Yes, the value is present. Sorry for the long wait.

Comment: My appologies, The value is not present under HKLM, It is present under HK Current User.